# How do I install Molsketch?

Tags: installation, cmake

I attempted to install molsketch by running make after running cmake at which point I received the output:

```
[  1%] Building CXX object libmolsketch/src/CMakeFiles/molsketch_LIB.dir/stereocenteritem.cpp.o
/home/brentonhorne/Downloads/Molsketch-0.2.0-Source/libmolsketch/src/stereocenteritem.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void Molsketch::StereoCenterItem::paint(QPainter*, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem*, QWidget*)’:
/home/brentonhorne/Downloads/Molsketch-0.2.0-Source/libmolsketch/src/stereocenteritem.cpp:66:17: error: ‘StereogenicUnit’ is not a member of ‘OpenBabel’
/home/brentonhorne/Downloads/Molsketch-0.2.0-Source/libmolsketch/src/stereocenteritem.cpp:66:17: error: ‘StereogenicUnit’ is not a member of ‘OpenBabel’
/home/brentonhorne/Downloads/Molsketch-0.2.0-Source/libmolsketch/src/stereocenteritem.cpp:66:43: error: template argument 1 is invalid
/home/brentonhorne/Downloads/Molsketch-0.2.0-Source/libmolsketch/src/stereocenteritem.cpp:66:43: error: template argument 2 is invalid
/home/brentonhorne/Downloads/Molsketch-0.2.0-Source/libmolsketch/src/stereocenteritem.cpp:66:51: error: invalid type in declaration before ‘=’ token
/home/brentonhorne/Downloads/Molsketch-0.2.0-Source/libmolsketch/src/stereocenteritem.cpp:66:97: error: cannot convert ‘OpenBabel::OBStereoUnitSet {aka std::vector<OpenBabel::OBStereoUnit>}’ to ‘int’ in initialization
/home/brentonhorne/Downloads/Molsketch-0.2.0-Source/libmolsketch/src/stereocenteritem.cpp:68:40: error: request for member ‘size’ in ‘units’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
/home/brentonhorne/Downloads/Molsketch-0.2.0-Source/libmolsketch/src/stereocenteritem.cpp:69:17: error: request for member ‘at’ in ‘units’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
/home/brentonhorne/Downloads/Molsketch-0.2.0-Source/libmolsketch/src/stereocenteritem.cpp:70:62: error: request for member ‘at’ in ‘units’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
/home/brentonhorne/Downloads/Molsketch-0.2.0-Source/libmolsketch/src/stereocenteritem.cpp:73:17: error: request for member ‘at’ in ‘units’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
/home/brentonhorne/Downloads/Molsketch-0.2.0-Source/libmolsketch/src/stereocenteritem.cpp:74:62: error: request for member ‘at’ in ‘units’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
make[2]: *** [libmolsketch/src/CMakeFiles/molsketch_LIB.dir/stereocenteritem.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [libmolsketch/src/CMakeFiles/molsketch_LIB.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

The output of cmake was:

```
-- Unit testing enabled, run make test to run them
-- Found OpenBabel Trunk with graphsym.h
Qt QTASSISTANT library not found.
creating /home/brentonhorne/Downloads/Molsketch_build/libmolsketch/src/include/molsketch
UIS = /home/brentonhorne/Downloads/Molsketch-0.2.0-Source/libmolsketch/src/mechanismarrowdialog.ui;/home/brentonhorne/Downloads/Molsketch-0.2.0-Source/libmolsketch/src/reactionarrowdialog.ui
Qt QTASSISTANT library not found.
UIS = /home/brentonhorne/Downloads/Molsketch-0.2.0-Source/molsketch/src/settings.ui;/home/brentonhorne/Downloads/Molsketch-0.2.0-Source/molsketch/src/drawwidget.ui
-- Test:  valence
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/brentonhorne/Downloads/Molsketch_build
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Durning *make*，I meet the same problem as yours at the point of 48%.
You need to change
Molsketch-0.2.0-Source/libmolsketch/src/stereocenteritem.cpp **line  66** as: `std::vector<OpenBabel::OBStereoUnit> units = FindStereogenicUnits(obmol, symmetry_classes);`
When compile reach 90%,I meet another problem：

> Molsketch-0.2.0-Source/molsketch/src/mainwindow.cpp:22:28: fatal
>   error: QAssistantClient: No such file or directory

My Qt version is 4.8.5.Qt remove QAssistantClient after 4.7+.My solution is,comment every line related to QAssistantClient in mainwindow.cpp and mainwindow.h.